# How to find the correct devicePaths to use in local storage for an Openshift Persistent Volume?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, cloud-storage

I've seen the docs to create Custom Resources for Local Storage: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.5/storage/persistent_storage/persistent-storage-local.html#local-volume-cr_persistent-storage-local

But not sure how to populate the `spec.storageClassDevices.devicePaths` field.

I've tried the `lsblk` command in one of my nodes and got this response:

```
sh-4.4# lsblk
NAME                         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
vda                          252:0    0   250G  0 disk 
|-vda1                       252:1    0   384M  0 part /boot
|-vda2                       252:2    0   127M  0 part /boot/efi
|-vda3                       252:3    0     1M  0 part 
`-vda4                       252:4    0 249.5G  0 part 
  `-coreos-luks-root-nocrypt 253:0    0 249.5G  0 dm   /sysroot
vdb                          252:16   0   200G  0 disk 
vdc                          252:32   0   200G  0 disk
```

Answer (score 0):

On **Linux** and other **Unix-like** systems your block devices are represented in the filesystem as files so each block device has its unique path, the same way as regular file.

Instead of running `lsblk` you can run `df` command which will show you those paths however it will show you only the devices which are already mounted.

All block devices on your system start with `vd` so you can simply run:

```
ls -l /dev/vd*
```

to list them all.

So if you want to mount e.g. your `vdb` and `vdc` disks, the values for `spec.storageClassDevices.devicePaths` will be `/dev/vdb` and `/dev/vdc`:

```
spec:
  ... 
  storageClassDevices:
    - storageClassName: "local-sc"
      volumeMode: Filesystem 
      fsType: xfs 
      devicePaths: 
        - /dev/vdb 
        - /dev/vdc
```